# Override luma theme default color

Tags: magento2.3, luma-theme

I am using `Magento 2.3.2`, I change the default color  `{CSS : luma theme }` to a custom color.

After a certain time, it returns to the default. How to solve this

Comment: You had override it in your custom theme ? How did you do ?

Comment: Do I have to create a child to edit style?

Comment: Yes, to work properly, you create a child luma theme, then you customise it as your needs

Comment: thnx for helping